# How to enlarge map in maps package within rstudio?

Tags: r, maps, rstudio

When I plot a map in Rstudio, using the maps package, the map is small and when I try to zoom in it stays small. I was wondering if there is a way to enlarge it.

I use e.d. this script from http://www.molecularecologist.com/2012/09/making-maps-with-r/

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
map("worldHires","Canada”, xlim=c(-141,-53), ylim=c(40,85), col="gray90”, fill=TRUE)
```

Does anyone know how to enlarge this image or is this just not possible due to lack of enough pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- First, there are a few problems with your code, particularly the `"` (double quote) characters. Below is the correction:

  `map("worldHires","Canada", xlim=c(-141,-53), ylim=c(40,85), col="grey90", fill=T)`
- Second, in answer to your question when I exported the plot from with RStudio as a .pdf and opened the .pdf it is indeed a vector file which you can zoom in and out of as expected. You can specify the default canvas size on export, either from the GUI or using a function like pdf()

Comment: thanks! So it's only possible to enlarge it when exported and not within RStudio?

Comment: I couldn't, but then I'm not familiar with the map() function. There might be a way to specify a larger canvas size. Check the arguments the function takes with `?map`

Comment: Also, if this answer resolves your query, don't forget to mark the question answered! Cheers.

Comment: I'm having the same problem! There is no zoom argument for the map function. I've put subplots on the map so I need to be able to zoom on the map prior to exporting. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3389288 I think your best bet is to open a new question, reference this question, and let me know so I can take a look. Please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can replicate your issue. Guidance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example